# Try to deploy an Angular 17 web app with proxy config, but it does not work in production

Tags: angular, proxy, production-environment

I'm really clueless about the error. Locally in dev mode, it works. But in production, the request return a web page instead of a RSS feed, as if the path was wrong and it return the root (home page instead).

Note: It's a firebase cloud project I try to deploy.

My `proxy.config.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "/rss": {
         "target": "https://baladoquebec.ca/podcast-name",
         "secure": false,
         "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

And the `angular.json` looks like:

```
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
    },
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "buildTarget": "halo-comm:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
            "buildTarget": "halo-comm:build:development"
        }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
},
```

And the `http.get` function looks like this:

```
getFeedList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('/rss', { responseType: 'text' })
        .pipe(
            map(this.extractFeedList),
            catchError(this.handlerError)
        );
}
```

Is there a way to debug or add trace to understand how the proxy works?

UPDATE:

I've found that in `firebase.json`, I can add config on `headers` and `redirects`. No success so far, but working on this solution.

UPDATE #2:

When I click on the redirect link https://mydomain.app/rss, it redirect to the url mentionned at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong but `proxy.config.json` or `proxy server` only works in local environment and only user to code, debug or test the application.

While to work in production or multiple 'environments' you need to set up enviroment files and build profiles for each env in `angular.json`. Now the `domianBaseURL` or  `your backend path` is should be specified in ENV's and writing an API interceptor to switch while in production with a production mode flag also works.

Can take a Reference from here
https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-environment-specific-defaults

Hope this helps :)